# jQuery: Animated container that resizes based on content size

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, containers

Here I'm trying to create an animated `div` container that would resize itself based on content size with an animation. The problem is that the size can't be easily calculated, which makes it hard to use common suggestions.

I reproduced the whole problem on link below and I'm looking for a hint to find the solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/csj78rgo/2/

My preferred way to solving this would be jQuery, jQuery-ui or Bootstrap JS.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="part1">
        <h3>TITLE</h3>
        <p>Some content</p>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="part2">
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="part3">
        <p>Some content</p>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
step = 0;
if (step==0) {
    $('#part1').show();
    $('#part2').hide();
    $('#part3').hide();
}  else if (step==1) {
    $('#part1').hide();
    $('#part2').show();
    $('#part3').hide();
} else if (step==2) {
    $('#part1').hide();
    $('#part2').hide();
    $('#part3').show();
}
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    border: 1px black solid
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are looking for, something like this perhaps: https://jsfiddle.net/csj78rgo/1/?

Comment: Yeah you got the solution I was looking for, can you post it here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything fancy to resize your container, once you hide content within it, it will automatically resize itself. You can use the `duration` parameter of jQuery's [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to animate the contents in and out.

```js
var step = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  if (step==0) {
    $('#part1').show("slow");
    $('#part2').hide("slow");
    $('#part3').hide("slow");
  }  else if (step==1) {
    $('#part1').hide("slow");
    $('#part2').show("slow");
    $('#part3').hide("slow");
  } else if (step==2) {
    $('#part1').hide("slow");
    $('#part2').hide("slow");
    $('#part3').show("slow");
  }

  if(step++ == 3)
    step = 0;
}, 1000);
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px black solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="part1">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    <p>Some content</p>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="part2">
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="part3">
    <p>Some content</p>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say using logic similar to the below; replacing the "$('#part1').show();" logic.

```
$('#part1').show();
var containerHeight = $('#part1').height();
$('#part1').hide();

$('#part2').hide();
$('#part3').hide();

$('.container').animate({height: containerHeight + "px"}, 400, "linear", function() {
    $('#part1').fadeIn(100);
});
```

The first 3 lines are to work-around a FireFox only bug, where it won't detect the height of an element unless it's visible. By showing it, getting the height, then hiding it.. it happens so quickly it won't show on the browser but you can get the height to animate to.

The animate has a callback function which will only show the new element after the container has re-sized enough to show it.

It will need some adaption to do what you want exactly, but there should be enough there for you to get the idea.